# Htaccess/robots.txt to allow search bots to explore main domain but not directory on other domain

Tags: .htaccess, hosting, bots, robots.txt

Ok, I understand the Title didn't make any sense so here I've tried to explain it in detail.

I'm using a hosting that gives me space for my domain and lets me "add on" other domains on it. So lets say I have a domain A, and I add on a domain B. Basically my hosting gives me a public_html where I can put stuff that shows when someone visits website A. But, when I add the domain B, it lets me put the content of B, INSIDE of that public_html so that website B.com can also be visited by going to A.com/siteB... Thats all good, except that Google has started indexing B.com as well as A.com/siteB, I'm ok with it indexing B.com, but I somehow want to prevent it from indexing A.com/siteB so that when people search for B, it doesn't end up showing A.com/siteB.

Any ideas? Let me know if the question is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /siteB
```

in the [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) in the root of your main domain. All bots that have manners will accept this, but depending on the frequency they visit your site you might have to wait a bit before the search engines update their datbases.

Additionally you could add a .htaccess with a redirect rule to /siteB/... that redirects requests that have been done using the siteA domain to http://siteB/... This will make everyone use the [canonical](http://www.socialpatterns.com/search-engine-marketing/cleaning-up-canonical-urls-with-redirects/) domain even if they browse to the lesser-favored one.

Comment: Thanks, I had used the same robots.txt for over a month but apparently it wasnt working, or maybe I hadn't waited enough. Anyways just implemeted the htaccess solutions.